# PHP Mysql Website Performance Measure

Tags: php, mysql, performance, web

Hi I want to measure my PHP MySQL websites performance i.e No of connections that can be made.How much load it can withstand.Please suggest me a tool for the above

Comment: `$start = time(); //Some script. echo time() - $start;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My sugestion: [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> The Apache JMeter™ desktop application is open source software, a 100% pure Java application designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance. It was originally designed for testing Web Applications but has since expanded to other test functions.

Comment: It's a client simulator. Doesn't matter if it's PHP, .NET, Java or anything else as long as your webpage is HTML

Answer (score 0):

For testing scalability / performance, I would recommend [tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/).

> The purpose of Tsung is to simulate users in order to test the
>   scalability and performance of IP based client/server applications.
>   You can use it to do load and stress testing of your servers. Many
>   protocols have been implemented and tested, and it can be easily
>   extended.